# When setting the 3D Viewport's Context to Texture Paint the previous Texture gets loaded

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a UV mapped mesh that I've painted a texture for, and I want to apply a different texture to it. When in Edit Mode, I can see the new texture applied to it, but when going to Texture Paint Mode the previous texture is suddenly assigned to the object.

See following video: https://streamable.com/ybn68

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the solution was choosing the image from the 3D View's Properties Panel > Slots > Canvas Image